# Store 1, 3 and another 1 bits at one byte

Tags: c#, bit

So When i want to store 2 `4 bits` numbers inside 1 `byte` I am do this:

```
var num1 = ...
var num2 = ...

byte b = (byte)((num1 << 4) | num2);
```

Now I have `3` numbers:

```
1 bit
2 bit
1 bit
And another 7 bits that can be zeros:

    var num1 = ... (1 bit)
    var num2 = ... (2 bit)
    var num3 = ... (1 bit)
```

So in this case what the operation I need to use In order to put all this numbers at one `byte` ?

Comment: You want to put 1+2+1+7 bits = 11 bits in one byte? Are you sure? And "...that can be zeros" means what? any bit can be 1 or 0, that is the definition, hard to fathom what you are trying to say here.

Comment: What exactly is the expected outcome? when u story multiple bits in a byte?, a byte is kinda fixed in its definition

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the `7` is a typo and should be `4`, then: very similar really;

```cs
int num1 = ...
int num2 = ...
int num3 = ...

var composed = (num1 == 0 ? 0 : (1 << 3)) // treat all non-zero as 1
             | ((num2 & 0b11) << 1) // take just two bits of num2
             | (num3 == 0 ? 0 : 1); // treat all non-zero as 1

// note composed here is an int, but you can simply cast to byte

// and decompose again
num1 = (composed >> 3) & 1;
num2 = (composed >> 1) & 0b11;
num3 = composed & 1;
```

---

And if the `7` *isn't* a typo: then that *doesn't fit*.